# Как сделать выборку данных из JSON массива по ключевому слову

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть JSON массив с объектами, в каждом объекте есть набор ключей, в которых может быть ключевое слово. Как вывести объекты, содержащие ключевое слово, если объект содержит больше 1 ключевого слова, то нужно вывести его несколько раз пример:

```
t_num | item | num(ключевое слово)
t_num | item | num(ключевое слово)
```

Пример JSON:

```
[{"id":"1","item":"Box1","one":"Tech1","two":"Tech2","three":"Tech3","four":"Tech2","five":"","six":"","t_one":"315","t_two":"306","t_three":"304","t_four":"111","t_five":"","t_six":""},{"id":"2","item":"Box2","one":"Tech1","two":"Tech5","three":"Tech3","four":"","five":"","six":"","t_one":"303","t_two":"315","t_three":"","t_four":"","t_five":"","t_six":""},{"id":"3","item":"Box3","one":"Tech1","two":"Tech1","three":"Tech3","four":"","five":"Tech2","six":"","t_one":"203","t_two":"218","t_three":"201","t_four":"","t_five":"145","t_six":""}]
```

Ключевое слово например: `Tech2`, в итоге должно вывести:

```
306 | Box1 | Tech2
111 | Box1 | Tech2
145 | Box3 | Tech2
```

Сейчас имею следующий код:

```js
$(function(){
  var data = '[{"id":"1","item":"Box1","one":"Tech1","two":"Tech2","three":"Tech3","four":"Tech2","five":"","six":"","t_one":"315","t_two":"306","t_three":"304","t_four":"111","t_five":"","t_six":""},{"id":"2","item":"Box2","one":"Tech1","two":"Tech5","three":"Tech3","four":"","five":"","six":"","t_one":"303","t_two":"315","t_three":"","t_four":"","t_five":"","t_six":""},{"id":"3","item":"Box3","one":"Tech1","two":"Tech1","three":"Tech3","four":"","five":"Tech2","six":"","t_one":"203","t_two":"218","t_three":"201","t_four":"","t_five":"145","t_six":""}]';
  var parse = JSON.parse(data);
  var len = parse.length;
  var item = "Tech2";
  for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
    if(parse[i].one == item){
      $("#text").append("<div class='t'>"+parse[i].t_one+" | "+parse[i].item+" | "+parse[i].one+"</div>");
    } else if(parse[i].two == item){
      $("#text").append("<div class='t'>"+parse[i].t_two+" | "+parse[i].item+" | "+parse[i].two+"</div>");
    } else if(parse[i].three == item){
      $("#text").append("<div class='t'>"+parse[i].t_three+" | "+parse[i].item+" | "+parse[i].three+"</div>");
    } else if(parse[i].four == item){
      $("#text").append("<div class='t'>"+parse[i].t_four+" | "+parse[i].item+" | "+parse[i].four+"</div>");
    } else if(parse[i].five == item){
      $("#text").append("<div class='t'>"+parse[i].t_five+" | "+parse[i].item+" | "+parse[i].five+"</div>");
    } else if(parse[i].six == item){
      $("#text").append("<div class='t'>"+parse[i].t_six+" | "+parse[i].item+" | "+parse[i].six+"</div>");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.t{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Получилось вывести:

```
306 | Box1 | Tech2
145 | Box3 | Tech2
```

Как сделать вывод нужным образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var data = '[{"id":"1","item":"Box1","one":"Tech1","two":"Tech2","three":"Tech3","four":"Tech2","five":"","six":"","t_one":"315","t_two":"306","t_three":"304","t_four":"111","t_five":"","t_six":""},{"id":"2","item":"Box2","one":"Tech1","two":"Tech5","three":"Tech3","four":"","five":"","six":"","t_one":"303","t_two":"315","t_three":"","t_four":"","t_five":"","t_six":""},{"id":"3","item":"Box3","one":"Tech1","two":"Tech1","three":"Tech3","four":"","five":"Tech2","six":"","t_one":"203","t_two":"218","t_three":"201","t_four":"","t_five":"145","t_six":""}]';
  var parse = JSON.parse(data);
  
  parse.forEach(val => filterTest(val));
  function filterTest(data) {
    var search = "Tech2";
    for (var key in data) {
      if (data[key] === search) {
        console.log(data['t_' + key]);
        $("#text").append("<div class='t'>" + data['item'] + " | " + key + " | " + data['t_' + key] + " | " + search + "</div>");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.t {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Используйте простой filter. 
Вот тут [описано](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) у Вас это будет `parse.filter(val => val === 'Tech2');`

Comment: а как в этом случае мне получить нужные json ключи, ведь этот метод вернет объекты?

Comment: Я думаю вы сами поменяете порядок вывода нужных данных, это только пример.

Comment: Спасибо за пример, это довольно интересно